# Meta query with multiple logic (AND / OR)

Tags: meta-query

I realise this has been asked before, but this feature seems to have been added in v4.1 and the accepted answers aren't helpful (they're pre-4.1).

How can I "chain" meta queries with ANDs and ORs? I've found this [Update on Query improvements in 4.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/) but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for my application.

I'd like to query posts where `flagged` is not `1` `AND` (`expiry_date` is in the future `OR` blank)

I've tried re-ordering the arrays and 'relations' without effect (there are definitely posts in the database which match this query).

The date part of the query works fine, but the addition of the `flagged` query returns no posts.

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array( 
        'key'     => 'flagged',
        'value'   => '1',
        'compare' => '!='
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'expiry_date',
            'value'     => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATETIME',
        ),
        array( //has no date
            'key'       => 'expiry_date',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Just having `flagged` there means you're going to search posts only with a meta key `flagged`. Are you sure you weren't looking for `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'` ?

Comment: All posts have a meta entry `flagged`, but some posts may not have this set (or set to `NULL`) while others will be set to `1`.

Comment: can you var_dump the SQL output with and without the "flagged" meta query? (this would be in the $wp_query->request value).

Comment: Solved: `flagged` was initiated to `NULL` which seemly prevented the query from working. Setting to `0` and the query works as expected.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it! Would you please post the solution as an answer and come back in a couple of days and accept it? This keeps the unanswered queue clear and makes the solution more visible to other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for performing the AND OR is as follows:

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array( 
        'key'     => 'flagged',
        'value'   => '1',
        'compare' => '!='
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'expiry_date',
            'value'     => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATETIME',
        ),
        array( //has no date
            'key'       => 'expiry_date',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
)
```

As a side note, it seems that post meta which are set to `NULL` (eg `flagged`) will not be returned by this query. Setting to any other value (such as `0`) resolves this issue.

Comment: life saver. Was stuck at this